# How to call function javascript at body tag to code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can i call function from body tag script to code behind? (not head tag) because my function always no defined

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Test(){
   alert(1);
}

</script>
```

And my code behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,GetType(), "Test", "Test(); ", true);
```

Comment: Just try adding 1 button and bind into your button click event.

Comment: i already add on click server but Test not defined

Comment: I tried your code and it worked well. I did not see no any matter. So can you explain more about your application and also what will you do?

Comment: i place the script at wrong place , i place outter form, after i place in the form it work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Test","Test();",true);
```

Comment: i try your solution but still Test() not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
```

Instead of asp button use html button . This way you can increase performance too

Comment: html markup : <input type="button" ID="Button1" value="Button" OnClick="Test()"/>